# Response from Foursquare Api is undefined- Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, foursquare

I want to get a photo from a foursquare venue using request in Node.js platform.
My id and secret are of course valid,and with this code i have the below result.However i want to get the prefix and suffix of the image in order to create the image as shown in Foursquare api https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/photos

The result as shown in the second image keeps being undefined,no matter if i try to reach meta or response or anything.What am i doing wrong?

```html
const request = require('request');
request({
  url: 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/59aa0677e17910245d942204/photos',
  method: 'GET',
  qs: {
    client_id: 'my_id',
    client_secret: 'my_secret',
    ll: '40.7243,-74.0018',
    query: 'coffee',
    v: '20171114',
    limit: 1
  }
}, function(err, res, body) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log(body);
  }
});
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse json. Try the following code:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(body).meta);
console.log(JSON.parse(body).response);
```

output:

> { code: 200, requestId: 'xxxxx' }
>   { photos: { count: 1, items: [ [Object] ], dupesRemoved: 0 } }

Comment: Thank you for the response!